# a:hover not working on menu li items

Tags: css, menu

I´m building a vertical menu in CSS, but I can´t get the a:hover to work, it´s just doing nothing. I´ve been searching and reviewing the code (I´m new to CSS), but can´t figure it out...if anyone has any suggestions, much appreciated :)

Here´s CSS:

```
.menu_container{
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 270px;
margin-top: 220px;  
}
.main_menu ul { 
padding: 0px; 
margin:0px;
list-style-type: none;  
}
.main_menu ul li {
padding-right: 25px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px; 
letter-spacing:4px;
text-align:right; 
line-height:35px;  
list-style-type:none;  
}
.main_menu ul li a  {  
text-decoration:none;  
color:#999;  
} 
.main_menu ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;  
color:#999;  
font-weight:bold;  
background:url(images/circle_grey.gif) right center no-repeat;
padding-right: 25px; 
float:right;
}   
.main_menu ul li a.selected  {
background: url(images/circle.gif) right center no-repeat;
padding-right: 25px; 
float:right;
color: #bc4c9b;
font-weight:bold;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_container">
<div class="main_menu">  
<ul>  
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>  
<li><a href="quienes_somos.html" class="selected" >QUIÉNES SOMOS</a></li>  
<li><a href="consultoria.html">Consultoría</a></li>  
<li><a href="capacitacion.html">Capacitación</a></li>  
<li><a href="academico.html">Académico / ARTÍCULOS</a></li>  
<li><a href="alianzas.html">Alianzas</a></li> 
<li><a href="proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>  
<li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>   
</ul>  
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just tested your code and the hover event seems to be working fine for me, what exactly is not working?

Comment: Hi, thanks for testing. It´s not doing neither the font-weight nor the image load. I noticed that if I put `a.selected` before `a.hover`, it applies the a:hover stlying over the selected item, without affecting the others (which is the opposite of what I´m trying to do, but might give a clue what´s going on). May be I´m misunderstanding the a:hover use? I thought it would specify a style for all li items except for the one that has the selected class asigned.

Comment: Take a look at this demo i put up, the `:hover` event is working fine (i removed the `float:left` declarations as they were interfering with a few things just for testing). http://jsfiddle.net/stMZv/1/

Comment: Hi, Andrés, thanks for the demo! I deleted the `float:right` that was both on `.main_menu ul li a:hover` and `.main_menu ul li a.selected` , and now the `a:hover` event is working :). So yes, you are right, that was interfering ideed. Thanks again :) Do you want to put it as an answer, so if someone searches the same thing doesn´t see a 0 answer question, since it´s solved?

Comment: De nada! Will post as an answer to give closure to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

The menu was being floated to the left on hover and also on the `.selected` class and that was what was causing the problem. Here are the fixed classes with the `float` properties removed:

```
.main_menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;  
  color:#999;  
  font-weight:bold;  
  background:url(images/circle_grey.gif) right center no-repeat;
  padding-right: 25px; 
}

.main_menu ul li a.selected  {
  background: url(images/circle.gif) right center no-repeat;
  padding-right: 25px; 
  color: #bc4c9b;
  font-weight:bold;  
}
```